# VS 2013 OpenCV Error: Cannot find or open the PDB file

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, visual-studio-2013

When i'm compilling an opencv example project, I have such error:

```
'opencv2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin\opencv_core248.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'opencv2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin\opencv_highgui248.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'opencv2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin\opencv_contrib248.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'opencv2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin\opencv_flann248.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'opencv2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin\opencv_imgproc248.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'opencv2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin\opencv_features2d248.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'opencv2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin\opencv_calib3d248.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'opencv2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin\opencv_ml248.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'opencv2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin\opencv_video248.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'opencv2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin\opencv_objdetect248.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
```

Comment: Did you build in Debug or Release? PDB files are the symbols that you can use to debug in the IDE.

Answer (score 4):

oh, this has been answered soo often here ..

first, this is no error. it's a warning. the *prebuilt* opencv libs indeed come without pdb files (dl size).

so, you can still run / debug *your own code*, but you can't dive into the opencv libs while debugging.

again, no error. if you still *need* that feature, you'll have to rebuild opencv locally using cmake, this will generate those pdb files, too.

Comment: No problem now. I destroyed it. Thanks

Comment: I don't remember sorry :) I did it yesterday